# Autodesk BIM360 upload file in Plans root

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

in Autodesk BIM360 Plans root folder, only project drawings and models are allowed to upload.
Using the Data Service Forge-API ([as described here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/upload-document/)) instead, we can upload and retrieve all kind of files also in Plans root folder (but these files are hidden on online client).

What is your advice?

Thanks,
Alberto

Answer (score 0):

The UI of the BIM 360 Docs product is design to show you 3D and 2D models that are hosted in the Plans folder. I understand that you can upload through the API, but that is not the right use of the Plans folder.

If you want to upload files and be able to access other kind of formats I will suggest upload them on the Project Files, which will be the right place to host them.